# Get a JSON API response using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to use wikipedia search api from javascript, I know it might be easier with something like jquery but I'd like to get a good grip on the basics before using frameworks.
Here is the code I wrote, but I never get the alert:

```
document.getElementById("go_search").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let wiki = new XMLHttpRequest();
    wiki.addEventListener("load", () => {
      alert(wiki.responseText)
    });
    wiki.open("GET", "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&utf8=1&srsearch=Albert+Einstein");
    wiki.send();

  })
```

The wikipedia adress is a search Albert Einstein, which is just to test if the code is working. Thanks for your help it is much appreciated!

Comment: There is an error in the console which will tell you the problem

Comment: Instead of listening to the `load` event, listen for the `onreadystatechange` event. The you can check the `readyState` and `status` of your `XMLHttp` object to know the status of the ajax call

Comment: Just a heads-up on the future :) [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) -> `fetch("https://en.wikipedia.org/...").then(response => response.json()).then(res => console.log(res))`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I did see the error and the fetch API seems like it would be really useful, appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `origin=*` to the URL query params to make JSON API requests to Wikipedia.

Change your request URL to

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=query&format=json&list=search&utf8=1&srsearch=Albert+Einstein
```

Comment: Thanks Abhijit, it worked. what the origin does is allow request between different domains right? will it work with any api or just wikipedia?

Comment: The Origin header tells the server from which website the client code originated. `origin=*` is just for the Wikipedia API.